# Put array translation in php class

Tags: arrays, class

this is my problem:

I have an array included in every page of my site with the translations.
The array is composed:

```
$translation = array();
$translation['0'] = 'aaa'; 
$translation['1'] = 'bbb'; 
$translation['2'] = 'ccc'; 
$translation['3'] = 'ddd'; 
$translation['4'] = 'eee';
```

I have a file for each language - the array is long.

If I call an array element inside a class, I get an error "Undefined variable".

How I can pass the external array elements to my class?

Thanks.

Ginetto

Comment: In constructor? As related method's arguments? Seriously, why did you choose to show the code that defines an array (and is, well, quite meaningless by itself) - but not the code that actually uses it?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify the language, but for assuming it's PHP, either pass the array variable by reference (not value) with &$translation in the arguments eg.

```
$my_object->doSomething(&$translation_arg);
```

to your class method (or constructor) OR you can access global variables by using 'global $translation' in your methods ie.

```
class MyClass {
    global $translation;
...
}
```

The first method is usually better.

Comment: Thanks for you answer; using your first solution, is there a waste of memory? My array has a lot of elements.

also, I have to receive the array in my class constructor?

Comment: No, there's no extra memory required ie you're not duplicating the contents of $translation_arg, merely using a reference to it. It's similar to C++ references, sort of like 'safer' or 'easier' pointers. They save your calling function from having to send an explicit pointer - you just write them as normal and the called function picks up the fact you're working on a reference to the parameter, not the value. (Not sure why this answer was voted down - I'm not precious about downvotes, but would be interested if I've made a mistake answering the question).